# How to view Google drive HTML as pdf in google drive

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I would like to share pdf in google drive but even with featurs of preventing downloading and printing still can download it image by image that's why i thought to use another way after some research I found pdf2htmlEX so after i convert my pdf to html I upload it in google drive but when i wanted to opended it's appear as html code not as pdf

any help to solve that issue and any idea to share pdf without be downloadble image by image

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to secure your PDF and keep people from downloading/screenshotting its contents. Unfortunately, even if you successfully convert the PDF to HTML, people will still be able to view and therefore download/screenshot the contents. It's hard to prevent piracy.

As for the issue regarding your HTML files displaying as HTML in Google Drive, Google Drive doesn't support this. Google Drive no longer renders HTML files as of August 31, 2015:

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html

If you're looking for a way to secure your PDF, most people will tell you that the simple answer is: **you can't**. Tools exist that help prevent screen recording and screen printing, but they're expensive and not foolproof. Someone can also just take a picture of their screen. The reality is that if you want to share content with the world through a PDF, you have to accept that it might be shared or stolen.

If you just want some basic protection through Google Drive, Google offers some advice for preventing copying and downloading:

> To prevent commenters and viewers from downloading, printing, or
>   copying your file:
>
> 1. Click Share or Share Add people.
> 2. In the bottom right, click Advanced.
> 3. Check the box next to "Disable options to download, print,
>      and copy for commenters and viewers."
> 4. Click Save changes.
> 5. Click Done.

[Source](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893)